# How do I set start year and end year of jquery date picker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I initialize a jquery date picker like

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

The showing the date picker from year 2000 to year 2020.

**EDIT:**

When i go to year 2000, the next time it shows from 1990, but any way I want to customize it.

How do I set the from year and to year that will fit for my requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker): The option is called [`yearRange`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-yearRange).

> Control the range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to today's year (-nn:+nn), relative to the currently selected year (c-nn:c+nn), absolute (nnnn:nnnn), or combinations of these formats (nnnn:-nn). Note that this option only affects what appears in the drop-down, to restrict which dates may be selected use the minDate and/or maxDate options.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, i am not able to accept this. The system say 'wait for 10 minutes'.

Answer (score 12):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '1945:'+(new Date).getFullYear()         
    });
});
```

this example for year start from 1945 to current year

Answer (score 8):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1972:2011'
    });
```

Should be work well.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
$('#license_expiry_date').datepicker({changeMonth: true, 
                                      changeYear: true, 
                                      yearRange: '-100:+100',
                                      maxDate: new Date(2100, 1,18) });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like following:

`'yearRange': '1945:'` - End year is the current one.

`'yearRange': '1945:+10` - Add +10 years to the current one.

`'yearRange': '1945:-10` - Subtract -10 years from the current one.

Answer (score 0):

#### start date must be limit at most 2 year selection

```
 $(document).on('change', '#startdate', function () {
        var current=$(this).val();
        var currentYear = current.split("-");
        var compareYear=(new Date().getFullYear()-1);
            if(compareYear > currentYear[0]){
                $('#limitMsg').text('this year must at most one year from current date');
                $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
            }else{
                $('#limitMsg').text('');
                $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
            }
  });
```