# How to change to dropdown menu in datepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker,
By default it is showing like

[Default date picker format](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#datepicker)

But I want months & year to be shown in drop down menu since to choose 1992,user has to click again and again.
So how to configure it.

Thanks.

Comment: You already had the api open, and didn't `ctrl+F` for *"dropdown"*?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Answer (score 0):

Use **[changeMonthType](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeMonth)** and **[changeYear](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeYear)**:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/dropdown-month-year.html)**

Answer (score 0):

**Try it :-**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  });
```

[Demo With Source Code](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)

And If you want to Set Year Range then Visit Below links.

[yearRange](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)

[Stackoverflow Example For Rear Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675747/how-do-i-set-start-year-and-end-year-of-jquery-date-picker)

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeMonth

I hope it will helpful to you.