# How to Set Year in Jquery Date Picker

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        }).datepicker("setDate", "0"); });
```

It shows Current Date (16-02-2016). But I need to Set 2016 as 2017.

How to Set the Year?

Comment: Answer here --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/5675802/3648578

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i set start year and end year of jquery date picker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675747/how-do-i-set-start-year-and-end-year-of-jquery-date-picker)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var today=new Date();
    $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date(today.getFullYear()+1, today.getMonth(), today.getDate())); });
```